is this a blender issue? why does exports to GLB look like the second image in some specific programs like noesis and in some specific mobile phones?

I checked normals, checked on various forums, checked on youtube, yet to find anything that even tells me what is happening.
One thing i found out is that some meshes look normal on these same problematic softwares and phones IF they have no skeleton, no animations and have never been rigged.... as soon as the mesh is attached to any skeleton at all it will look bugged when exported.
edit:
apparently if the mesh as a material I can toggle off backface culling and it seems that at least on some softwares it fixes the problem, but then again why does the problem happen even when there are no materials?

Do you have Alpha Blending on?

@scurest no idea where to find it or how to turn it off but I found backface culling in the material settings and toggled it off, seems like it fixed the problem... but then again why does the issue happen even if the exported mesh has no materials attached to it?
